# Get value in a cell based on the reference obtained from value in another cell in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There are three sections in the same spreadsheet, Section 1 and Section 2 are available and Section 3 needs to be populated. Following is the demo of how

Section 1 : Date, Value1, Value2

Section 2 : Date, Value1 [Sorted version of a subset of Section 1, w.r.t. Value1]

Section 3 : Date, Value2.

How to fill Section 3 ?

Section 3 will have same size as of Section2. 
The ith row of Section3 needs value2 from Section1 for which, Date is same as that for same row i of Section2.
In other words, ith row of Section2 will tell the date corresponding to which I need to find the Value2 from Section 1.

How to get this value.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly soon after asking this question, found an answer.

The key here is to use a VLOOKUP formula, here is the reference : [VLOOKUP Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) The example there demonstrates the usage fairly well.

However, for this question the formulae would be something like

`=VLOOKUP(COLUMN_ID_OF_DATE_FROM_SECTION1, RANGE_OF_SECTION_1_THAT_HAS_BOTH_THE_DATE_COLUMN_AS_WELL_AS_VALUE2_COLUMN_HERE_THAT_WOULD_BE_ENTIRE_RANGE_OF_SECTION1,COLUMN_ID_OF_VALUE2_FROM_SECTION1, TRUE_IF_DATE_COLUMN_SECTION1_IS_SORTED_FALSE_OTHERWISE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of match and indirect of address to get your value

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(K1,G:G,0),3))

MATCH gets the row number having the matching criteria., ie the date in this case

INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row, column)) get the value at that row, column index

Assuming your data to be as below. In case of change, pls reply with sample data
[image]